# Creating own AppStore for iOS Enterprise Distribution

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

We have created own AppStore to distribute our application. Its simple web-application, where displayed link:

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&amp;url=https://appstore.ourserver.com:443/AppStore/Plists/15e122e839dfdaa7ce969536f94aecf6/1.plist" >Install</a>
```

If we access url https://appstore.ourserver.com:443/AppStore/Plists/15e122e839dfdaa7ce969536f94aecf6/1.plist from safary all is ok - file downloads. But when we click on link and iTunes attempts to download 1.plist it reported error that can't establish connection to appstore.ourserver.com. We analysed logs of IIS on our server, no any request to 1.plist arriving.

How can we debug, why iTunes can't connect to our server? What can we try to fix problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with invalid server certificate. We have checked it on https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest and discovered, that certificate requires SAN with all domain mappings. When we created valid certificated and trusted root certificacte on device, all become ok.